# Python, Object-Oriented

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently took an exam for a class covering python. We were told to create a class called *Place* and two child classes, *City* and *Home*. The *Place* objects had a name and a location (None if not entered). *City* objects had the same but added a population and a mayor. *Home* objects had a name and location and added a number of beds and occupancy. Each object also had a *visited* boolean, starting at false.

Ex -->

```
indiana = Place('Indiana')
iu = Place('IU Campus', btown)
library = Place('Wells Library', iu)
btown = City('Bloomington', indiana, 400, 'Jim')
rental = Home('Rental House', btown, 4, 3)
```

I was supposed to implement a method *visit()* that changed the place's *visited* boolean to true and, if it was in a *location* change that location's *visited* boolean to true and print out as following...

```
Test code: 
library.visit()
indiana.visit()
```

The output:

> You visit Wells Library.
>   That means... You visit IU Campus.
>   That means... You visit Bloomington.
>   That means... You visit Indiana.
>   You already visited Indiana.

Any help with implementing the *visit()* method?

Comment: create a global list(initially empty one). check if you have already visited the place, if not append the place into the list.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

With python 3:

```
class Place:
    def __init__(self, name=None, location=None):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.visited = False

    def visit(self):
        if self.visited:
            print(f"You already visited {self.name}.")
        else:
            print(f"You visit {self.name}.")
            location = self.location
            while location is not None:
                print(f"That means... You visit {location.name}.")
                location.visited = True
                location = location.location

class City(Place):
    def __init__(self, name, location, population, mayor):
        super().__init__(name, location)
        self.population = population
        self.mayor = mayor

class Home(Place):
    def __init__(self, name, location, num_beds, occupancy):
        super().__init__(name, location)
        self.num_beds = num_beds
        self.occupancy = occupancy
```

Then when you do:

```
indiana = Place('Indiana')
btown = City('Bloomington', indiana, 400, 'Jim')
iu = Place('IU Campus', btown)
library = Place('Wells Library', iu)
rental = Home('Rental House', btown, 4, 3)

library.visit()
indiana.visit()
```

Output:

> You visit Wells Library.
>   That means... You visit IU Campus.
>   That means... You visit Bloomington.
>   That means... You visit Indiana.
>   You already visited Indiana.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example and used comments to show how each piece works. I've used another subject as an example that should hopefully lead you in the right direction. This uses 1 parent class and 2 child classes. Each child has a unique function and both have replaced 1 or more functions that were already declared in the parent.

```
class gamePlatforms:
    played = False
    name = "blank"
    location = "blank"
    total_games = "0"

    # play function that will be inherited by Console and PC classes
    def play(self):
        if self.played:
            print("You've already played games on it.")
        else:
            print("First time gamer! Welcome!")
            self.played = True

    # print_nerdiness function that will be inherited by Console and PC classes, but will be replaced by their own
    # functions (polymorphism)
    def print_nerdiness(self):
        if self.played:
            was_played = "Yep!"
        else:
            was_played = "No... it's sad."

        print("Name of console: " + self.name)
        print("Location of console: " + self.location)
        print("Has it been played: " + was_played)

    # set functions, good practice to create get functions as well, but I skipped that.
    def set_name(self):
        self.name = input("What is the name of the console: ")

    def set_location(self):
        self.location = input("Which room is the console in: ")

    def set_game_total(self):
        self.total_games = input("How many games do you have: ")


# Console: child class of gamePlatforms
class Console(gamePlatforms):
    controllers = "0"

    # can take 0 to 2 arguments
    def __init__(self, name=None, total_games=None):
        self.name = name
        self.total_games = total_games

    # This is a unique function for this child class
    def set_controllers(self):
        self.controllers = input("How many controllers does the console have: ")

    # This function replaces the one from the parent class
    def print_nerdiness(self):
        if self.played:
            was_played = "Yep!"
        else:
            was_played = "No... it's sad."
        print("-" * 20)
        print("Name of console: " + self.name)
        print("Amount of controllers: " + self.controllers)
        print("Location of console: " + self.location)
        print("Has it been played: " + was_played)
        print("Amount of games: " + str(self.total_games))


# PC: child class of gamePlatforms
class PC(gamePlatforms):
    OS = "blank"

    # can take 0 to 2 arguments
    def __init__(self, name=None, total_games=None):
        self.name = name
        self.total_games = total_games

    # this is a unique function to this child class
    def set_OS(self):
        self.OS = input("What operating system does the computer have: ")

    # this function replaces the parent function
    def set_name(self):
        self.name = input("Enter the model of the pc: ")

    # this function replaces the parent function
    def print_nerdiness(self):
        if self.played:
            was_played = "Yep!"
        else:
            was_played = "No... it's sad."

        print("-" * 20)
        print("\nModel of PC: " + self.name)
        print("Operating system: " + self.OS)
        print("Location of pc: " + self.location)
        print("Has it been played: " + was_played)
        print("Amount of games: " + self.total_games)


# creating a PC object, but only passing the model
myPC = PC("Dell 2000")

# creating a Console object passing Atari as the console name and total_games to 5
myConsole = Console("Atari", 5)

# Calling PC class functions to fill information, will not directly call variables outside the class object.
myPC.set_location()
myPC.set_game_total()
myPC.set_OS()

# Calling Console class functions to fill information, will not directly call variables outside the class object.
myConsole.set_location()
myConsole.set_controllers()

# Look at activity first
myPC.print_nerdiness()
myConsole.print_nerdiness()

# Time to play! This will be like your visit command
myPC.play()
myConsole.play()

# Look at activity again, it's different
myPC.print_nerdiness()
myConsole.print_nerdiness()
```